# Why does calling mail() after opening a file cause sendmail to attempt a write on that file?

Tags: php, sendmail, file-descriptor, postfix-mta, selinux

Why does calling `mail()` after opening a file cause sendmail.postfix to attempt a write on that file?

Proof of concept:

```
<?php

$h = fopen('/var/www/test.txt', 'w');

mail('example@example.com', 'Test', 'Test Data');
```

SELinux message:

```
type=AVC msg=audit(1669742006.859:131227): avc:  denied  { write } for  pid=1886412 comm="sendmail" path="/var/www/test.txt" dev="vda1" ino=29380975 scontext=system_u:system_r:system_mail_t:s0 tcontext=system_u:object_r:httpd_sys_rw_content_t:s0 tclass=file permissive=0
```

If I close the file before `mail()` or remove the variable assignment `$h =`  the message is not written.

Directory info:

```
drwxrwxr-x+ 2 deploy deploy unconfined_u:object_r:httpd_sys_rw_content_t:s0 4096 Nov 29 17:19 www
```

```
# file: www
# owner: deploy
# group: deploy
user::rwx
user:www-example:rwx
user:deploy:rwx
group::rwx
mask::rwx
other::r-x
default:user::rwx
default:user:www-example:rwx
default:user:deploy:rwx
default:group::rwx
default:mask::rwx
default:other::r-x
```

This happens when running via Apache > PHP FPM running under a dedicated system account (www-example). I could not reproduce via the CLI.

- Platform: Rocky Linux 8.7 (Green Obsidian)
- Postfix version: 2:3.5.8-4.el8
- PHP version: PHP 8.0.26

A PHP or sendmail bug?

Comment: Does the mail send even with SELinux preventing the access? Do any additional accesses happen if you do `setenforce 0`? When you attempted to reproduce it via the CLI were you using su as `www-example`? Is `mail.log` set in `php.ini`?

Comment: Yes, the mail sends regardless so setenforce 0/1 has no effect on the result and the access is still logged. I used `sudo -u www-example -s` in my CLI test to start a shell. mail.log is not set in php.ini. I do now know that open file descriptors are inherited by processes started by PHP which helps a little to understand, but not why sendmail is trying to write to them.